# Finding $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{\sqrt{(b-x)^2+c^2}}dx$

Tags: integration, electromagnetism

How do we find

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(ax)}{\sqrt{(b-x)^2+c^2}}dx$$

I have no idea on how to even begin approaching this. Can I get a hint?

EDIT:

I've got to this integral from a physics exercise in electromagnetism, not sure how well it fits here, but here is the exercise:

> In an area $y<0$ there's emptiness, and in an area $y>0$ there's magnetism: $\overrightarrow{M}=M_0cos(\beta x)e^{-ay}\hat{y}$. Find the magnetic potential in every point in the space.

I used this formula: $\overrightarrow{J}_M=\overrightarrow{\nabla} \times \overrightarrow{M}$ and substituted it in $\overrightarrow{A}(\overrightarrow{R})=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int\int\int_{v'} \frac{\overrightarrow{j}(\overrightarrow{R'})}{|\overrightarrow{R}-\overrightarrow{R'}|}dV'$ and ended up with the integral in the question.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think that this integral is expressible in an elementary form? Many integrals are not so expressible, and I expect that this is one of them.

Comment: If your had explicit bounds, say from $-\infty \to \infty$ then I suspect that residue theory could be an option.

Comment: You could expand $\sin(a x)$ into the exponential form, the exponential into its limit form, and use [this closed form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+%281%2Br+x%2Fn%29%5En%2F√%28%28b-x%29%5E2%2Bc%5E2%29), but taking the limit afterwards will be hard. Are you sure there were no integral bounds from the physics exercise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $a,c>0$. Put $x=b-t$ to get $$\sin(ab)\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(at)\,dt}{\sqrt{c^2+t^2}}-\cos(ab)\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(at)\,dt}{\sqrt{c^2+t^2}}.$$ The second integral is zero, and the first one is $2K_0(ac)$ (see [Basset's integral](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32#E11)).